# Removing characters from multibyte strings in php

Tags: php, utf-8, multibyte

I made this but only works in latin charsets

```
function str_ink($str){ 
    $arr =  str_split ($str);
    $new=array();
    foreach($arr as &$a){
        if(ctype_alnum($a)){
            array_push($new,$a);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably format your code, also you're missing a `}` at the end, not sure if that's your problem or not.

Comment: I'll give you 2 hints, unfortunately I have to sleep now :), first use this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153002/using-arabic-characters-with-ctype-alnum) for matching instead of ctype_alnum which work only for ascii , second thing , when dealing with strings you can directly use it like array ex `$str[0]`, to deal with unicode you have to use each 2 strings as one like this `$str[0].$str[1]` is the first character, while `$str[2].$str[3]` is the second one!